# Number of recursive function calls

Tags: python, recursion

I'm a total beginner at Python and I was wondering how to get the number of recursive function calls ?
is it 2^n (if n is the argument given)

Comment: You'll need to clarify. The number of recursive calls depends on the function you're using. Are you just trying to count them? In that case, you can pass in an optional argument to count them.

Comment: an argument like what ?

Comment: Time complexity is not depends on recursion it's depends on your function (algorithm) and yes it should be recursively function with O(2^n) but also there some cases when recursion function uses less or more time, for ex O(n!) When you generate all permutation recursively.

Answer (score 1):

The amount of calls completely depends on the algorithm. Sometimes it is 2**n, but other times it could be n! or a quadratic, or anything else.

To work out how many it is, you can you use my method. This might get shunned by some other users, but using a global counter is a quick and easy way to count the amount of function calls.

```
function_calls = 0
def fibonacci_recursive(n):
    global function_calls
    function_calls += 1
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    elif n == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return fibonacci_recursive(n-1) + fibonacci_recursive(n-2)
ans = fibonacci_recursive(20)
print("There were",function_calls,"function calls.")
```